# jQuery each array problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each, array-splice

I'm looping through an array using the jquery each function. I assign a temp variable for it to loop through instead of the actual array itself as I am modifying the original array using splice. However, it looks like `temp` is getting modified even when I splice `array`.

```
function example (Data, index, array) {
            var temp = array;
            $.each(temp, function(i, v) {    
                if(Data["b"+v].length > index) {
                    //do stuff
                } else {
                    array.splice(i,1);
                }
            });
            if(array.length > 0) {
                example(Data, index+1, array);
            }
}
array = [1,2,3,4]
Data = {"b1":[a,b,c,d],"b2":[e,f,g,h], "b3":[i,j], "b4":[k,l,m,n]};
example(Data, 0, array);
```

On the third call of example, on the 4th iteration of temp, v becomes undefined and therefore the next line pumps out an error of "cannot read length of undefined". This happens right after `array.splice(3,1)` is called which seems like temp is pointing to the same place as array instead of being a copy of it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays and objects are assigned by reference. `temp` and `array` reference the same array. You can create  a shallow copy using [`.slice()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice):

```
var temp = array.slice();
```

Instead of creating a copy, you could iterate over the array in reverse order:

```
for(var i = array.length; i--; ) {
    if(Data["b"+array[i]].length > index) {
        //do stuff
    } else {
        array.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Going through array in reverse order seems much cleaner, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

temp is just a reference to the same array, so temp and array are the same thing.  You want to make a copy, like so:

```
temp = array.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assignments in JavaScript are by reference, it doesn't copy the object. Eg...

```
var obj1 = {};
var obj2 = obj1;
obj2.hello = "world";
console.log( obj1.hello ); // logs "world"
```

This is because `obj1` and `obj2` are pointing to the same object in memory.

If you want to make a copy of an array, the [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice) method can be used...

```
var arrayCopy = myArray.slice(0)
```

Now `arrayCopy` & `myArray` can be edited independently. However, be aware that although the arrays themselves are independent, they point to the same objects...

```
arrayCopy[0] === myArray[0]; // true
arrayCopy[0] = {my: "new object"};
arrayCopy[0] === myArray[0]; // now false
```